# How do I prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{19}]$ is not a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains, quadratic-integer-rings

> How do I prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{19}]$ is not a UFD? Moreover, how do I prove that $(7,3+\sqrt{19})$ is not a principal ideal?

This is the first time I'm dealing with a quadratic integer ring where $\omega>0$, so I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Use the norm $N(a+b\omega)=a^2-b^2\omega^2$ and check for irreducibility (see the answer below)

Comment: @Moya I tried that. But I have to solve whether $a^2 - 19b^2 = 2,3$ has no solution. I was stuck at this point.

Comment: Reduce modulo $19$, and check that $2$ and/or $3$ is not a square modulo $19$.

Comment: @user26857 I'm confused now. That shows that $(7,3+\sqrt{19})$ is principal. What's wrong in belows answers?

Comment: $1={\color{red} 7}\cdot 3+\color{red}{(3+\sqrt{19})}\cdot(6-2\sqrt{19})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is incorrect; $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{19}]$ *is* a UFD. The [Minkowski bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound) for the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{19})$ is $\sqrt{19}$, and the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{19})$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{19}]$.  It is a theorem that the ideal class group of a number field is generated by the ideals of norm less than the Minkowski bound.

Hence, to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{19}]$ is a UFD, it is sufficient to check that the $\mathbb{Z}$-primes 2 and 3 (the only primes less than $\sqrt{19}$) factor into principal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{19}]$.

This is equivalent to checking that one of $\pm 2$ is a norm, and one of $\pm 3$ is a norm.  (In the real quadratic case, we must not forget about the sign of the norm!)  Since $\left(\frac{-2}{19}\right) = \left(\frac{-3}{19}\right) = 1$, we should choose the minus sign in both cases, and we can find these elements: $N(13 - 3 \sqrt{19}) = -2$ and $N(4 - \sqrt{19}) = -3$.

Therefore $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{19}]$ is a UFD.

Comment: Oh.. Is there a direct proof for this? I don't know the concept of Minkowski bound.

Comment: @Rubertos I don't know of any direct proof. The Minkowski bound is the standard way to determine the class number of a number field. Are you really being asked to solve this problem without the Minkowski bound?

Comment: Not sure. This problem was on a qualification exam for algebra.

Comment: what is the idea behind $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{19}] = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{19}]} \implies$ it is enough to check $(2)$ and $(3)$ factor into principal ideals ?

Comment: @user1952009 See edits.